# Blazor Server 8: Authentication and Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am currently working on a Blazor project and implementing JWT token-based authentication. However, I'm facing challenges in getting it to function correctly. Below is a snippet of my code for reference:

My Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

I'm uncertain whether I should include the Authentication middleware in my setup.

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authentication =>
   {
    authentication.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authentication.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(option =>
{
    AppConfiguration? config = applicationSettingsConfiguration.Get<AppConfiguration>();
    byte[]? key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config!.Secret);

    option.SaveToken = true;
    option.TokenValidationParameters = new()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = config.Audience,
        ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});
```

Even after adding the necessary setup, things aren't working as I hoped. Also, pages like 404 errors, or redirecting users to login when they're not authenticated, and handling access denied situations, aren't behaving the way they should.

Comment: "whether I should include the Authentication middleware" If you don't use Authentication middleware,  you need to  store jwt token then custom validate jwtToken . How do you do it ? " aren't behaving the way they should."  Could you show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts?

Comment: I save and check a custom JWT token using the `PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider`. I've created a Razor component that redirects the user to the login page if they're not authenticated, and I'm using the `AuthorizeRouteView`. I wrap my component in the NotAuthorized component. This setup works well when you click on a link that leads to a view with the authorize attribute. However, if you manually navigate to that view, it displays the browser's 401 error page instead.

Comment: I   manually navigate to that view, it doesn't display the browser's 401  . How do you define `PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider` ?

Comment: Yes, i also tested that with default template created by Microsoft it works,  here is my code for the `presistentAuthenticationStateProvider` `AuthenticationState? state = new(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(GetClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
AuthenticationStateUser = state.User;
return state;`

Comment: if it's not too much of a problem i could share my Anydesk code with you

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. Sorry, I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: @QingGuo i found the solution to the problem https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52063#issuecomment-1817420640